# implementing an onclick event on the nodes of a spacetree with Javascript Infovis Toolkit

Tags: javascript, infovis

I'm using the Infovis library to plot a spacetree.

Unfortunately there is a problem when implementing event on nodes as all nodes are false.

There already is a thread about it on the associated google group: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/NJtbe9hq5bQ

The solution given was to fix the 'contains' in NodeTypes: 
https://github.com/philogb/jit/blob/master/Source/Visualizations/Spacetree.js#L1370

I copy-pasted the new NodeTypes implementations, unfortunately it's still not working (nodes are still all false).

Any idea?

Edit: it's possible to do something close by creating a label on plot of the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug as stated in the question, so only two solutions:

1. correcting the library as shown [on line 1370 of Spacetree.js](https://github.com/philogb/jit/blob/master/Source/Visualizations/Spacetree.js#L1370)
2. using a work-around

I managed to implement the desired functionality by creating a label using the onPlot option for each node.

Comment: This is great thank you.  The improved code from #1 worked perfectly.